# How could a server fight against this kind of datetime of attack?

Tags: date, datetime, server, timestamp

I'm currently coding a project that requires the storing, of timestamps, and then sends notifications on the timestamp. Now although this is a hobby-type project, it made me think about a certain vulnerability:

If your server's CPU can execute 5 billion cycles per second (5GHz which is quite generous), and it's job is to notify on an exact timestamp. Let's say May 31st at 12:00:00, then the CPU would constantly check if that is the time, then execute the notifications if it is. Now the vulnerability is that let's say it takes 5 cycles to execute each notification (random number most likely much more) then in the 1ms of correct time, it can only execute 1 million notifications. If millions of users all scheduled a notification for that exact same time, the CPU wouldn't be able to send notifications to everyone.

So is there a solution to this problem, or is this not a problem in the real world?

Comment: Well, if the requirement is to send out more notification than the capacity allows, then the only solution is getting more capacity. For example have several servers work in parallel. So if you need high accuracy, setting a limit on the number of identical of very close timestamps is probably a good idea.

Comment: Alarms are usually served as 'best effort'. After the timestamp, the server will send notification, obviously some early and some later. Ev. the server will save the state at timestamp and give all users the same answer (without changing the response, also if the original data change). -- I think it is mostly a design problem (you have always constrain, so you must find a good design for your particular case). -- Note: in past, some NTP servers had a problem: many routers were asking regularly and at same time the time (overloading the server); -- Do not consider CPU timestamp precise.